# Remote Ejb bean deployed on Weblogic called from Tomcat web application

Tags: java, tomcat, ejb, jndi, weblogic12c

I have created an remote EJB bean using EJB 3.1 and deployed it on web logic 12c. Now through a simple java client I am able to access the remote bean. It is working fine.

Java Client Code:

```
Context ctx = null;
          Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
          ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory"); 
          ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7001");
        try {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(ht);

}
```

My next approach is to call this remote bean in a web application that is deployed in Tomcat 7. But it is throwing exception

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.

I am using the following code to call the ejb bean :
Properties properties = new Properties();

```
        properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        properties.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "weblogic.jndi.factories:weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.url");
        properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7001");
        properties.put( Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "weblogic");  
        properties.put( Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "weblogic1");
        try {
          Context ic = new InitialContext(properties); 
}
```

What to do to make it work.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should have either the wlthint3client.jar or the wlfullclient.jar on your web application classpath. Both are available from weblogic distributions.

More information on their usage can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/web.1111/e13717/basics.htm#SACLT117)

Comment: I have wlfullclient.jar in web application classpath under the lib folder.

Comment: That should solve the issue as far as I know. Can you check if the jar contains the said class file? If it does and you still see the same error, there is something wrong with your setup.

Comment: I provided the jar under the WEB-INF/lib folder in the application.Now it iscoming out with the above exception but throwing exception in next line.
javax.naming.NamingException: Unhandled exception in lookup [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 211 .

Comment: Did you create a client jar for your ejb ?

Comment: I did not create a client jar for ejb. I copied the same code that is woirking for simple java client within the web app class and then called the web app. Then it is throwing exception in the line 
 HelloSpring hb = (HelloSpring) ic.lookup("HelloSpring#com.sample.HelloSpring");
However it is working well in simple java client.

Comment: I suspect you used an IDE like eclipse to run your stand alone program. And since it was a test program, maybe that was packaged with the ejb project itself? In which case eclipse would have added the remote intf and other request / response objects to the classpath. When you run the client on a foreign server you will have to create a client jar and place it in the classpath (just like how you did the wlfullclient.jar)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68211/discussion-between-ramp-and-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

Work for me adding wlclient.jar **and** wlthint3client.jar (in this order) on classpath.

In my case I was trying to invoke EJB from the test class. To get the instance I did this way:

```
weblogic.ejb.spi.BusinessObject obj = (weblogic.ejb.spi.BusinessObject) context.lookup("MyEJBRemoteMappedName#br.com.ejbclient.MyEJBRemote");
br.com.ejbclient.MyEJBRemote myEJB = (br.com.ejbclient.MyEJBRemote) obj._WL_getBusinessObjectHandle().getBusinessObject();
```

I'm using wls12130.